# Comparaison of Chern Connections (and curvatures) of two metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold. Let $h$ and $k$ be two metrics on $E$ such that
$$k(\cdot,\cdot)=h(u\cdot,\cdot)$$
for some bundle endomorphism $u$. I am looking for a good reference that relates the curvatures $F_h$ and $F_k$ of the Chern connections.

Comment: Is $k$ a Hermitian metric anymore?

Comment: @ArcticChar Sure, you take $u$ to be self adjoint with respect to $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate in local coordinates. Write $u = u^\alpha_\beta\in \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb C)$. Then

$$ k_{\alpha\beta} = u_{\alpha}^\gamma h_{\gamma\beta}$$

or just $k = uh$. Since the chern connection with respect to $h$ is given by $h^{-1} \partial h$,

$$k^{-1} \partial k = h^{-1} u^{-1} \partial u h + h^{-1} u^{-1} u \partial h = h^{-1} u^{-1} \partial u h + h^{-1} \partial h.$$

and thus the Curvatures satisfy

$$ F_k - F_h = \bar\partial (h^{-1} u^{-1} \partial u h).$$

Comment: You seem to have a great grasp of complex geometry. Would you mind recommend to me books/notes to start to learn complex geometry? I've read smooth manifolds theory and Riemannian geometry a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @SiKucing I highly recommend Griffiths & Harris, Huybrechts and Demailly.

Comment: @SiKucing Besides Bang Phan Khoa's choices (which are all great), there's a little book by Kodaira (I think it's called complex manifold) which is also great.

Comment: Thank you both ArcticChar, @BangPhamKhoa. I'll check them out.

Comment: @ArcticChar: You mean Morrow and Kodaira?

Comment: Yes, @TedShifrin Thank you. It's been a while I pick up that book.....

Comment: @ArcticChar In Donaldson's "Anti self-dual Y-M connections..." page 4 he writes that in this setup we would have $\partial_k=u^{-1}\circ \partial_h\circ u$, $\partial$ represents the (1,0) component of the connection. Where does that come from?